# Delete similar lines csh

Tags: regex, duplicates, csh, similarity

I've seen several articles on deleting duplicate lines, but I need something a little more specific.  Here is an example of some raw data:

```
11111 AA 1  date1
11111 BB 64 date1
11111 BB 64 date2
...
11111 BB 64 date64
11111 BB 64 date1
11111 BB 64 date2
...
11111 BB 64 date64
11111 BB ## date1
11111 BB ## date2
...
11111 BB ## date##
22222 AA 1  date1
22222 BB 64 date1
22222 BB 64 date2
...
22222 BB 64 date64
22222 BB 64 date1
22222 BB 64 date2
...
22222 BB 64 date64
22222 BB ## date1
22222 BB ## date2
...
22222 BB ## date##
```

Note: Where ## is some number < 64.

I need to edit that file so it looks something like this:

```
11111 AA 1  date1
11111 BB 64 date1
11111 BB 64 date1
11111 BB ## date1
22222 AA 1  date1
22222 BB 64 date1
22222 BB 64 date1
22222 BB ## date1
```

I've seen several examples of using awk, sed, or ed along with regex to match the first part of a line.  My confusion is with the occurance of the "BB 64" and "BB ##" and not just deleting all BB lines but the first.

Vital Info: Running this csh script on a Solaris v5.8

The AA lines are not important in this question except to know they are there (we are not doing anything with them).

Here's essentially what I've got so far (still having syntax issues from looking at examples using other languages, so if you can correct please do):

```
sed 'N;(\d{1,8}\sBB\s\d{1,2}.+\n);P;D' filename
```

If I were not getting errors due to syntax, I am sure this would delete all BB lines but the first "BB 64 date1."  I think my sed regex above is based on uniq but only matches the frist part of the line instead of the entire line because I will need the first date of each BB (if there are more than 1 series of BB 64 for each 11111, 22222, etc the output should contain an identical BB 64 line for each series [just date1]).  Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for first question, well formatted, sample input, required output and sample code!. A once in a month event! But, that is one heck-of-a sed expression :-). It will help if you edit your question to tell us what you think the sed is doing. But agree with below, sort | uniq is probably the better approach. Good luck to all.

Comment: you think? I cant make head or tail of what he wants, but given the output I'd start with grep  date1.

Comment: Unfortunately, date1 can be today's date, 2 months from now, or even a year from now.  I don't think grepping for the date would be feasible in my case.  I think my best bet would be to do a foreach line, pull the ## as a counter and delete every line but the first until ## is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `sort -k4,4 | uniq` would do the trick? (or `sort +3` if the Solaris version is sufficiently old.)

Comment: The input is already sorted, but I do not think uniq will work because the lines I want to remove are not identical due to the date being different for each in a series of BB.  Also, if there are more than one series of BB 64 lines for a 11111, 22222, etc, then I will need the date1 lines for each (so I may need some duplicates).

Comment: So what exactly are the "duplicates" you're trying to remove?  And why does "11111 BB 64 date1" show up twice in your sample output?

Comment: What we are looking at is a list of charges that occur some number of times with a maximum number of 64.  So, if someone wants more than 64, they have to order it twice.  So, you see 11111 BB 64 date1 twice because you had 11111 BB 64 date1 through date 64 twice in the input (we only want the first occurrence).

Comment: We are not really deleting duplicates, per say, because each line we delete is slightly different due to the date.  And, of course, there is the added complication of NEEDING duplicate lines when there is more than one series of 64 orders.

Comment: But if you only want the first occurrence, why did you keep both of them when you were showing what you want to get?

Comment: Lets say someone wanted 130 BB's.  They would need to order 64, 64, and 2.  So you would get something like a group of 111111 BB 64 date1 through date 64, another group just like it, then a group of 11111 BB 2  date1 through date2.  In order to be able to tell that 130 were ordered, I will need the first line of the first group of 11111 BB 64 date1 through date64, the first line from the second group, and finally, the first line from the 11111 2  date1 through date2.  This way we can still do 64 + 64 + 2 = 130 and not have a line for every single date.

Comment: My feeling you'd be best off to code this in some high(er) language like python